# When I click play the app crashes

Tags: android

I created an app that when I hit the play button it should play an MP3 file I put in the raw folder. However when I hit play the app just disappears and there is no error code. This is my code from my Main.Activity.java file. I assume the problem to be in here. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?-continuation-I've take multiple suggestions from this site and this is the current look of my project's code and the error I get.

```
    package com.games.illusionary.fortnitemusicplayer;


import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player;
    AdView nAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9224132391435572~8710572578");
        nAdView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        nAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }








    public void play(View v) {

        stopPlayer();
        player.start();


    }

    public void pause(View v) {
        if (player != null) {
            player.pause();
        }
    }

    public void stop(View v) {
        stopPlayer();
    }

    private void stopPlayer() {
        if (player != null) {
            player.release();
            player = null;
            Toast.makeText(this, "MediaPlayer released", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopPlayer();
    }
}
```

this is the error I am getting, it is highlighting player.start on line 42

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
        at com.games.illusionary.fortnitemusicplayer.MainActivity.play(MainActivity.java:42)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: create a [mcve]

Comment: Please add more details to your question. I think it's better to post the error.

Comment: I've tried everything suggested.  It still won't give me any audio.  I might just try starting over from scratch and see what that does

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
}

public void play(View v) {
    if (player != null) { 
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            stopPlayer();
        } else{
                player.start();
        }
    }else{
  /* player returns null, check if        
 player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
 is not returning null, if it's  returning null issue is with initializing media player */
   Log.e(getClass().toString, "MediaPlayer returns null");
 }
}
```

Comment: could you show an example of how to do that? thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in my PC, it's give me error too, I don't know what is the error but I know the solution, just use `Activity` class instead of `AppCompatActivity` like this :

```
package com.games.illusionary.fortnitemusicplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer player;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void play(View v) {
    if (player == null) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlayer();
            }
        });
    }

    player.start();
}

public void pause(View v) {
    if (player != null) {
        player.pause();
    }
}

public void stop(View v) {
    stopPlayer();
}

private void stopPlayer() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.release();
        player = null;
        Toast.makeText(this, "MediaPlayer released", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopPlayer();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing Mediaplayer object globally like below then run your app again:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        player = Mediaplayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song);

    }


    public void play(View v){

     stopPlayer();
     player.start();
}
```

`Mediaplayer player;`

This declares a variable but does not initialize it (The object reference will be null).

`MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);`

This creates a MediaPlayer instance but does not store the reference anywhere.

Comment: I did this and the app no longer crashes but it doesn't play anything.  Any idea why?

Comment: I think you should move `player = Mediaplayer.create(this, R.raw.song)` outside the if() statement. or declare `player = Mediaplayer.create(this, R.raw.song); ` in the onCreate() method

Comment: None of it worked but thank you for your help though

Comment: What do you get? Any error? What does the logcat shows. Try removing that conditional and in place simply call `player.start();`

Comment: 08-18 22:29:13.534 2235-2235/com.android.phone E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC
08-18 22:29:13.534 2235-2235/com.android.phone E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getCarrierPackageNamesForIntent: No UICC

Comment: But it works fine by my side. See some edits I made. But it should play. That's the simplest/common way of playing audio file withe Mediaplayer

Comment: What conditional is it that you thought I should remove?

Comment: I was referring to the one that checks for the player being null then. if(player == null){} and sets incompletionListener that calls stopPlayer() method

Comment: But you should get something to the logcat when your app crashes!